# Javascript ES5 Array functions. forEach second "This Value" argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I'm newbie in Javascript. And I faced the following question.

As stated [here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do), almost all ES5 Array functions (forEach, map, filter, every, some) can take additional second argument.

> If it specified the function is invoked as if it is a method of this second argument. That is, the second argument you pass becomes the value of the **this** keyword inside of the function you pass.

```
array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
array.map(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

On the contrary:

```
array.reduce(callback, [initialValue])
array.reduceRight(callback, [initialValue])
```

> Note that neither reduce() nor reduceRight() accepts an optional argument that specifies the this value on which the reduction function is to be invoked. See the **Function.bind()** method if you need your reduction function invoked **as a method of a particular object.**

What does it mean: "to be invoked as a method of a particular object"? Could anyone provide some example how it may affect on my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of javascript important feature as ***functional*** language is that you can pass function as params(aka, `callbacks`) to wrapping function(aka, `higher order function`),  and the `context`(aka, `this` keyword) of those callbacks is hard to reason about as you never get to know when and where(though many time owned by the global object like `window` in browser) they will be called, so if you're using `this` in those callbacks, `Function.bind` is a good way to "pin" the context of the callback while `arrow function` auto binds to the enclosing context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. In the callback function, the `this` value will be the second argument passed to the array method. If you won't use `this`, then the argument is irrelevant and you don't need to pass it.

```js
"use strict";
[0].forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
  console.log(this); // 1234
}, 1234);
```

Note that in sloppy mode, the `this` value is converted to an object. So if you omit the argument or use `undefined`, you will get the global object instead.

If you need something similar with `reduce`, then use `bind`:

```js
"use strict";
[0, 1].reduce(function(prevValue, currValue, index, arr) {
  console.log(this); // 1234
}.bind(1234));
```

Comment: and without it, `this` would be context of where method is used. Like `window` if run directly in browser console

Comment: @Oriol so, why do we need that thing? why don't just do the following `[0,1].forEach(function(val, ind, ar) {   let necessaryScope = this; })` without any `bind` invocations?

Comment: @IvanTalalaev It's not much useful if you use a function expression. But if the function is defined somewhere else you may need to pass some `this`

Comment: @Oriol I see, thank you. And this might be useful with arrow functions `() => {}` because of [scope difference](http://jsrocks.org/2014/10/arrow-functions-and-their-scope/#scope) ?

Comment: @IvanTalalaev Yes, arrow functions don't have a `this` binding, so you get the same value than in the enclosing context.