# confused again by javascript this

Tags: javascript, foreach, this

some updates:
thank all for all your help. i guess this might be the key confusion point: "this" in the param area is not considered "inside" the function, and thus will not follow the rule (this points to the obj the method is called on) mdn specified. example below:

```
someObj {
    someF(//but if "this" shows up here, it doesn't point to someObj) {
        //when called, "this" here will point to someObj
    }
}
```

original question:

After reading many docs, I thought I had a good understanding of this, but I was wrong.

The example below is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
function Counter() {
  this.sum = 0;
  this.count = 0;
}
Counter.prototype.add = function(array) {
// Here "this" points to obj
  array.forEach(function(entry) {
    this.sum += entry;
    ++this.count;
  }, this);
  // ^---- Note, why it points to obj, not array [2,5,9]???

// Here "this" points to obj
};

const obj = new Counter();
obj.add([2, 5, 9]);
obj.count;
// 3 
obj.sum;
// 16
```

I understand:

- The needs to pass in `this` to a `forEach`, otherwise in the callback function, `this` would point to global/window (non-strict mode).
- Within most areas of `function(array)`, `this` points to obj (created from new `Counter()`), as shown by the comments.
- How the callback function uses "this" passed from forEach as the 2nd param. I don't have any question about it

But based on this [article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) 
specifically:

> "As an object method, when a function is called as a method of an
>   object, its this is set to the object the method is called on."

Shouldn't the `this` (highlighted by ^---Note) passed into the callback point to the array object, i.e., [2,5,9] in this case. Why would it point to obj instead of the array?

Thanks a lot for the help, it's just so confusing.

Comment: `forEach` is not part of the object. It is called on `array` which is a different object than the `this` inside `add` which points to Counter instance. So to access Counter instance variable you need to pass `this` which will replace the `array` usual `this`. If you don't `this` inside `forEach` points to `array`.

Comment: See also [Javascript ES5 Array functions. forEach second “This Value” argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41664168/215552)

Comment: thanks, @GillesC. quote from mdn "The same notion holds true for methods defined somewhere on the object's prototype chain. If the method is on an object's prototype chain, this refers to the object the method was called on, as if the method were on the object." 
so forEach is on array's prototype chain and should point to array. yes, we need to pass this, but the "this" passed in is within the array.forEach function call, within which "this" should already mean [2,5,9], not obj

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey. i have no question about how the 2nd this is used within the callback function of forEach. my question is, the method (forEach) here is called on the object (array[2,5,9]), why "this" in its parameter area points to obj, not array[2,5,9]

Comment: @GillesC and btw, if i don't pass "this" as forEach as the 2nd param, the "this" within callback will point to window in non-strict mode, not array

Answer (score 0):

> the needs to pass in "this" in forEach, otherwise "this" in internal function would point to global/window (non-strict mode).

The value of `this` depends on how the function is called. You can't see the code which calls the callback function you pass to `forEach` (it is internal to the browser). As it happens, it does call it that way, so it is `window` (if you don't pass a second argument to `forEach`).

> As an object method, when a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on

This is irrelevant. You aren't calling the callback function as a method of an object. You're passing it to `forEach` … and then `forEach` is calling it.

You *are* calling `forEach` as a method of the array, so *inside the `forEach` function* — which you can't see because it is internal to the browser — `this` will be the array.

> Why it would point to obj instead of the array?

Because `forEach` is explicitly designed to call the callback function in such a way that the second argument to `forEach` is the `this` value inside the callback function.

You quoted the documentation that said so.

Comment: actually forget about the callback. i have no question about what's inside forEach callback. my question is why the "this" passed in is not [2,5,9]. the "this" shows up in the function call of forEach, which is on the prototype chain of object array. then why it doesn't point to the array.

why it's irrelevant? that's actually the key of my question. MDN says explicitly this points to the object the method is called on. here what's object: array [2,5,9]. where is the "this": within the forEach method parameter area, called by array

Comment: @user3236895 — You're calling `obj.add()` not `somearray.add()`. That's why the comment says `// Here "this" points to obj`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably see it easier in the following passing in a reference to the object's `this` as the `thisArg` of forEach()

```
Counter.prototype.add = function(array) {
  //here "this" points to obj
  const _self = this

  array.forEach(function(entry) {
    // _self passed in as second argument is now `this`
    console.log(this === _self) // true

    this.sum += entry;
    ++this.count;
  }, _self);
  // ^---- passing in reference to the `add` object instance `this`


};
```

Comment: i have no issue with this implementation, cuz you stored this (obj) to _self and you pass _self, which is perfectly fine.  but when you pass "this", as a method (on the prototype chain), it should point to array, not obj. shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is stemming from the words "called on" in the quote from MDN, and I wouldn't say that is your fault. It doesn't really sound wrong that to say, in the case of `obj.add([2, 5, 9])`, `obj.add` is being "called on" `[2, 5, 9]`. However, what they're trying to say is that the `add` method is being "called on" `obj`.

Regardless of how you want to word it, the way it works (in general) is if you're calling a function from a property of an object, that object is what `this` will point to inside that function. In the case of `obj.add([2, 5, 9])`, the `add` function is being accessed via the object `obj`, so `obj` is set to `this` inside that call of `add`.

Comment: i don't think i misunderstand it. actually, i'm applying the same logic.

obj.add([2, 5, 9]): 
***what's the object? obj
***what should this point to within add? obj

then same logic:
array.forEach(......., this)
***what's the object? array [2,5,9]
***what should this point to within forEach ? array

Comment: i'm using the same logic. tell me what's the object and method here: array.forEach(.........., this); and then tell me what "this" here should point to

Comment: @user3236895 If you're asking what this `this` is -> array.forEach(..., `this`) then see my answer. That `this` points to `obj` because that's `Counter.prototype.add`'s `this`. It has nothing to do with `forEach`'s `this`, it's just being passed into `forEach`.

Comment: @user3236895 just posting this to let you know I edited my comments, I'll delete this at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is exactly why [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) were introduced. They are more tightly bound to your enclosing closure.

```js
function Counter() {
  this.sum = 0;
  this.count = 0;
}
Counter.prototype.add = function(array) {
  array.forEach(entry => {
    /* 
      Because we are using an arrow function here, it is using the 
      enclosing closure (which originates from `obj`).
    */
    this.sum += entry;
    ++this.count;
  });

};

const obj = new Counter();
obj.add([2, 5, 9]);
console.log(obj.sum);
console.log(obj.count);
```

From the linked documentation:

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this from its enclosing scope.

Comment: i know the result of both arrow and traditional function. i'm asking why. using arrow function as an example: "it is using the immediate closure". shouldn't the "immediate closure" be array.forEach instead of obj.add? and what "this" should be within array.forEach? according to mdn's doc, shouldn't "this" point to array because forEach is called on "array"?

Comment: Arrow functions do not have their own `this`, it's inherited. The immediate closure I referred to is where `array.forEach` is called, not where `this.sum` appears.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect this. Also to be consistent with the documentation, I replaced `immediate` with `enclosing`.